# Component not refreshing after mapStateToProps is fired

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

The component saves your answer to a question when clicked and re-renders to show the selected answer. Or at least that's the goal.

The action is fired, data is passed to the reducer and eventually mapStateToProps fires with the updated data. All of it works, but it does not re-render the component.

My configuration is pretty simple and has been working in the past. I have been careful not to mutate the state and double-checked the variable names but the component still won't re-render.

Action

```
  // SAVE ANSWERS 
  export function saveAnswer(answer, questionNum) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const { answers } = Object.assign({}, getState());
      let newAnswers = answers
      newAnswers[questionNum] = answer

      dispatch({ 
        type: actionTypes.SAVE_ANSWER,
        answers: newAnswers
    })
    }
  }
```

Reducer

```
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    switch (action.type) {

        case actionTypes.SAVE_ANSWER:
            newState.answers = action.answers
            return newState

        default:
        return state
  }
}
```

Component Connection

```
...
//Connect Redux
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log('mapped', state)
    return {
      settings: state.settings,
      answers: state.answers
    }
  }
  const mapDispatchToProps = { saveAnswer }

  const connectedQuestion = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Question)

  export default connectedQuestion;
```

Component head

```
class Question extends React.Component{

    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );

        this.clickedAnswer = this.clickedAnswer.bind( this );
    }

    static async getInitialProps ({query}) {
        return {query}
    }

    render() {
        console.log('rendered', this.props.answers)
        const {settings, query} = this.props
        const currentNumber = parseInt(query.number)
        const currentAnswer = this.props.answers[currentNumber]

        const question = settings.questions[currentNumber - 1] || {}
...
```

**New Edit**

I added a line to my mapStateToProps function to force a re-render. It works (but obviously very wrong) and proves that Redux connect does not see the changes made.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      settings: state.settings,
      answers: state.answers,
      rand: Math.random()
    }
  }
```

Although when I log the state in this function, answers clearly go from `[]` to `[{Answer}]`.

Comment: Where are you actually committing the action to trigger this redux change?

Comment: I just added the action @ChristopherNgo